# Any update with Google apps, because script has stopped working?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

Can anyone help with a script which has stopped working:

It's a html/css form created (last year) to get the responses on a google spreadsheet alongside the the files uploaded within a folder. It was working fine until beginning of this year, but it doesn't anymore. I mean as usual, I run a function + deploy app, I get the link and the form appears, but upon submission I get nothing, blank page and the spreasheets doesn't contain anything.
Thanks a lot for your guidance.

Here are my codes:

Form.html

```html
<script>
  // Javascript function called by "submit" button handler,
  // to show results.
  function updateOutput(resultHtml) {
    toggle_visibility('inProgress');
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
    outputDiv.innerHTML = resultHtml;
  }

  // From blog.movalog.com/a/javascript-toggle-visibility/
  function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
    else
      e.style.display = 'block';
  }
</script>


<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style type="text/css">

img {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width:500px;
      height:170px;
     ;
}

form {
    width:450px;
    padding:30px;
    margin: auto;
    background: #FFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
}

h2 {
    width:450px;
    padding:30px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #FF8500;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #DADADA;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #DADADA;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #DADADA;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
}

h1 {
    background: #2A88AD;
    padding: 20px 30px 15px 30px;
    margin: -30px -30px 30px -30px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    font: normal 30px 'Bitter', serif;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
    border: 1px solid #257C9E;
}

h1 > span {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 2px;
    font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

label {
    display: block;
    font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #888;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="file"],
textarea,
select {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #B0CFE0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
}

section{
    font: normal 20px 'Bitter', serif;
    color: #2A88AD;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

section span {
    background: #2A88AD;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border: 4px solid #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: -45px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: -3px;
}

input[type="button"], 
input[type="submit"]{
    background: #2A88AD;
    padding: 8px 20px 8px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    font: normal 30px 'Bitter', serif;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
    border: 1px solid #257C9E;
    font-size: 15px;
}
input[type="button"]:hover, 
input[type="submit"]:hover{
    background: #2A6881;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.28);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.28);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.28);
}


</style>

<div id="formDiv">
<!-- Form div will be hidden after form submission -->
<img src="http://www.greenman-advertising.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/header_problemSolving_03.jpg">
<form id="myForm" runat="server">
<h1>Job application<span>Apply now and get the opportunity to join us!</span></h1>
<section> <span>1</span>Personal details</section>
    Full name: <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="First name & Last name"/><br/>
    Date of birth: <input type="text" name="birth" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"/><br/>
    Nationality:  <select name="nationality">
    <option>Test1</option>
    <option>Test2</option>
    <option>Test3</option>
     </select><br/>
     Marital status:  <select name="marital">
    <option>...</option>
    <option>Married</option>
    <option>Single</option>
         </select><br/>
    Please state the age of your children who will be registered in our school: <input type="text" name="children" placeholder="Example: 5;9;12 or 0"/><br/>

    <section> <span>2</span>Experiences and qualifications</section>
    Years of experience:  <select name="years">
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>10+</option>
    </select><br/>
    Highest qualification obtained: <input type="text" name="qualification" placeholder="Example: Degree, Master, .."/><br/>
    Educational qualification obtained: <input type="text" name="educational" placeholder="Example: QTS,PGCE,CELTA, .."/><br/>
    English language level:  <select name="profiency">
    <option>...</option>
    <option>Fluent English proficient</option>
    <option>Advanced</option>
     <option>Intermediate</option>
    <option>Early intermediate</option>
    <option>Beginner</option>
    </select><br/>
    <section> <span>3</span>Position applied for</section>
    Subject:  <select name="subject">
    <optgroup label="Teaching">
    <option>...</option>
    <option>Arts</option>
    <option>Biology</option>
    <option>Chemistry</option>
    <option>Computer Science</option>
    <option>English</option>
    <option>Math</option>
    <option>Physics</option>
    <option>Science</option>
    <option>Social Studies</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Other">
    <option>...</option>
    <option>Principal</option>
    <option>Deputy principal</option>
    <option>Educational spervisor</option>
    </optgroup>
    </select><br/>
    Grade level ( or Section):  <select name="grade">
    <option>...</option>
    <option>Higher grades</option>
    <option>Lower grades</option>
    <option>IGCSE</option>
    <option>AS</option>
    <option>A2</option>
    <option>SAT</option>
    </select><br/>
<section> <span>4</span>Contact details</section>
    Email: <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com"/><br/>
    Phone number: <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="[+]code country/phone number"/><br/>
    Skype: <input type="text" name="skype" placeholder="username"/><br/>
<section> <span>5</span>Attachments</section>
    CV (pdf/doc/docx only): <input type="file" name="myFile"/><br/>
    Qualification (scan): <input type="file" name="myFile2"/><br/>
    Other qualification (scan): <input type="file" name="myFile3"/><br/>
    Passport (scan): <input type="file" name="myFile4"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Apply"
      onclick="toggle_visibility('formDiv'); toggle_visibility('inProgress');
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateOutput)
          .processForm(this.parentNode)" /><br/>
</form>
</div>

<div id="inProgress" style="display: none;">
<!-- Progress starts hidden, but will be shown after form submission. -->
Uploading. Please wait...
</div>

<div id="output">
  <!-- Blank div will be filled with "Thanks.html" after form submission. -->
</div>
```

Code.gs

```js
var submissionSSKey = '1urIXPV2NdsqTJ5zXJb1_t_EdsY7Kuh3VcSBJ4cnPIEg';
var folderId = "0B0lYW3YSUvX2ZDc0WnhJdFhkQk0";

function doGet(e) {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Form.html');
  template.action = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  return template.evaluate();
}


function processForm(theForm) {
  var fileBlob = theForm.myFile;
  var fileBlob2 = theForm.myFile2;
  var fileBlob3 = theForm.myFile3;
  var fileBlob4 = theForm.myFile4;
  
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var doc = folder.createFile(fileBlob);
  var doc2 = folder.createFile(fileBlob2);
  var doc3 = folder.createFile(fileBlob3);
  var doc4 = folder.createFile(fileBlob4);


  // Fill in response template
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Thanks.html');
  var name = template.name = theForm.name;
  var birth = template.birth = theForm.birth;
  var nationality = template.nationality = theForm.nationality;
  var marital = template.marital = theForm.marital;
  var children = template.children = theForm.children;
  var years = template.years = theForm.years;
  var profiency = template.profiency = theForm.profiency;
  var qualification = template.qualification = theForm.qualification;
  var educational = template.educational = theForm.educational;
  var subject = template.subject = theForm.subject;
  
  var grade = template.grade = theForm.grade;
  var email = template.email = theForm.email;
  var phone = template.phone = theForm.phone;
  var skype = template.skype = theForm.skype;

  var fileUrl = template.fileUrl = doc.getUrl();
  var fileUrl2 = template.fileUrl = doc2.getUrl();
  var fileUrl3 = template.fileUrl = doc3.getUrl();
  var fileUrl4 = template.fileUrl = doc4.getUrl();

  // Record submission in spreadsheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSKey).getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 18).setValues([[name,birth,nationality,marital,children,profiency,years,qualification,educational,subject,grade,email,phone,skype,fileUrl,fileUrl2,fileUrl3,fileUrl4]]);

  // Return HTML text for display in page.
  return template.evaluate().getContent();
}
```

Thanks.html

```html
<div>
    <h2>Thank you <?= name ?>, <br>your application has been received.</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that you need this:  `template.action = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();`  That could be causing an error.  Plus, you don't need the `e` in `doGet(e)`.  You can remove that.

Comment: I would remove `runat="server"` from the form tag.

Comment: Nitpick: a huge chunk of your pasted code is irrelevant to the question. Much easier in future Stack Overflow posts to edit it down to be just the function/code in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, something has recently changed.  The default sandbox mode is now `IFRAME`.  Your `doGet()` function does not designate a sandbox mode, so it now defaults to `IFRAME`.  This has changed the behavior of your form.  You have an `<input>` tag that is a button of the `submit` type.  This causes the form to issue either a GET or POST request when the form is submitted.  That causes the screen to go blank, and is probably interfering with the `google.script.run.myfunction()` call to the server.  Change the input button type from `submit` to `button`.

Currently:

```
<input type="submit" value="Apply"
```

Change to:

```
<input type="button" value="Apply"
```

I modified the code for the function named `toggle_visibility`

```
if(e.style.display !== 'none')//Modified this line
```

Was:

```
if(e.style.display === 'block')
```

The style could be many different settings.  If it's `inline` for example, then that would break the code.  But if it's `!== "none"`, then if it's anything but `none`, then it's obviously being displayed.

Here is a link to a shared Apps Script file:

[Link to Shared Apps Script File](https://script.google.com/d/125dG42eB9lM4SPq64p0dpR2CBH4ohfHiqu9TvFNM8s4Ra7pt-7kHXoTM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks a lot, as always first to help. I've made the change you suggested. As for the function could you please give me further guidance (what shall I do to make it work?), as I've managed to do all of that without a deep understanding of all the issues. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Following your advice, I've visited this page [Migrating to IFRAME Sandbox Mode](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/migration/iframe#setting_the_link_target_attribute)

and made the following change:

```
function doGet() {
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Form.html');
template.action = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
return template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

and I changed the type to "button" but nothing is happening: it keeps at "Uploading. Please wait..." for ever

Comment: I never would have seen your answer unless I'd happen to see that there are now two answers to the question, and took a look.  If you make a comment, then that shows up in my inbox.

Comment: Sorry, I mean I've tried for months but couldn't get something to work, a real novice though I've managed to look everywhere. Would you mind helping me Sandy, that would be great !! Thanks

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated

Comment: I've got something working.  I created a new Apps Script Web App.  Do you want me to make it public here, or you can see my profile, and send me an email.

Comment: Well maybe we could share it so people can benefit from it as well. Thanks again

Comment: I put the link at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm going to explore what you've done and try to understand, and of course get something to work. I'll keep you informed

Comment: I changed the way that the name is being put into the Thank You file.  I got the file as a string, and then just replaced some text with some other text.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sandy, you did a great job helping me to solve this issue..works as I wanted !

Comment: I've done some more work on the input validation.  There is a required list.  If found empty, and is required, the field is turned red.

Comment: Great job Sandy it works perfectly, so I can set/add which field is required at line 9 of JS_Main_Form.html file: requiredList = ['name','birth'] ?

Comment: I did add the other fields, thank you, but do you think I could have the choice to require certain attachments as required as well, because when adding their names in requiredList it submit the data anyway even without attachment